# Limit number of threads calling a method in Spring (Boot)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, interceptor

We have a Spring Boot service like this:

```
@Service
public class XXXDataService {
    public XXXModel resolveData(){
    } 
}
```

The `resolveData` method fetches data from a datasource and returns it. In general it can handle several threads asking for data at the same time. But not more then `n` threads at the same time.

Is there a Spring-build-in solution to restrict the number of threads accessing a method.

Something like `@Synchronized(maxParallelAccesses=10)`.

Hint 1: It is important that all the other Spring interceptors are also not `fired`, for example a transaction should not be started until the method is not blocked anymore.

Hint 2: I don't wan't to restrict the overall number of threads of the application but only having some kind of method synchronization with size > 1.

Comment: I don't think Spring provides a built-in solution for that. Normally I would limit the number of threads running with `FixedThreadPool(n)` or implement custom logic in the method using  `Semaphore(n)`. Good question anyway, I'll follow the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Spring or even Java provides a build-in annotation to do that. But that logic can be implemented with a `Semaphore`:

```java
@Service
public class XXXDataService {

    private Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(10);

    public XXXModel resolveData(){
        semaphore.acquire();
        //... logic accessible by max 10 threads concurrently
        semaphore.release();
    } 
}
```